# SQL statements to ROLLBACK but Audit inserts to COMMIT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions

SQL Server 2012

I have a Master stored proc, which calls several other 'child' stored procs.
The master proc encapsulates the child procs in a transaction.

Throughout the master and child procs, there are many inserts into an audit table.

If the process succeeds, I get a detaied chain of events. If the process fails and rolls back, I would like to have a record of the last child proc processed in the Audit table, but the whole thing is rolled back, including the audit data.  Is there a way to selectively commit the audit inserts while rolling back the child proc changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much a "nope". All work (inserts, updates, deletes) done on **tables** within a transaction are all-or-nothing.

An awkwardly manual option is to keep track of the data being processed in one or more variables, passing them back and forth between the procedures. If everything is committed, ignore the variables; if you have to roll back, you can dig the data you'd want to keep out of them.

Comment: One impressively awkward but functional method of doing this is to store ALL of the SQL Statements that you would update the audit log with in a varchar(max) @variable while you execute them in sequence. If the process fails and rolls back, you can see where it failed by the SQL in the variable and any information in your error tracking data, and update the log appropriately.This will even let you see the logged information that was rolled back, without the data needed.  Its a kludge and a hideous pain, but it is accurate when implemented well.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a table variable in the master procedure and inserting the return code of each child procedure into the table variable.  Table variables are not affected by transactions, whereas temp tables are.

At the end of your master procedure, you can select from the table variable to return the results of your child procedures.