# How do you write to a table in a new transaction in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, commit, rollback

We have a requirement to log messages to a the database in our stored procedures - basically writing to a table.  However if the transaction needs to be rolled back, we loose these logs.

Is there any way to write these logs (table inserts) in a new or different transaction to ensure they are persisted, regardless of the transaction of the current stored procedure?

Comment: See also https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2010/10/17/logging-messages-during-a-transaction.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL statements to ROLLBACK but Audit inserts to COMMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107449/sql-statements-to-rollback-but-audit-inserts-to-commit)

Answer (score 1):

Abuse the fact that Variables(including table) are exempt from transactions. Store logs in a table var, insert from it after doing your regular transaction.

This should be enough for your logging needs.

One obvious downside of this is that you won't be able to monitor messages in "real time", using (nolock), so consider inserting both into your **LogTable** and **Table Variable** and only use the **TableVariable** on *Rollback*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Andrew - here's a simplified version of the MS example your link.

The main point is creating a linked server:

```
'EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'linkbackServer,@srvproduct = N' ',@provider = N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc = @@SERVERNAME '
```

With 2 options

Don't use the parent transaction

```
'EXEC sp_serveroption @serverName,N'remote proc transaction promotion','FALSE'
```

Allow remote procedure calls

```
'EXEC sp_serveroption @serverName,N'RPC OUT','TRUE'
```

Here's all the code to create and test

```
-- Create the linked server

    use tempdb
    declare @serverName varchar(10) = N'loopback'
    if exists (select * from sys.servers where is_linked = 1 and name = @serverName) begin
       exec sp_dropserver @server=@serverName
    end

    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = @serverName,@srvproduct = N' ',@provider = N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc = @@SERVERNAME 
    EXEC sp_serveroption @serverName,N'remote proc transaction promotion','FALSE' 
    EXEC sp_serveroption @serverName,N'RPC OUT','TRUE' 


    -- Create the logging and testing tables
    if exists (select * from sys.all_objects where name = 'ErrorLogging' and type = N'U') begin
        DROP TABLE ErrorLogging
    END
    CREATE TABLE ErrorLogging (logTime DATETIME, id int, msg VARCHAR(255)) 

    if exists (select * from sys.all_objects where name = 'TestAT' and type = N'U') begin
       DROP TABLE TestAT
    END
    CREATE TABLE TestAT (id INT PRIMARY KEY) 
    GO

    -- create the logger stored proc
    if exists (select * from sys.all_objects where name = 'MyLogger' and type = N'P') begin
      DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyLogger]
    END
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE MyLogger 
       @errNumber INT,
       @errMessage varchar(50)
    AS BEGIN
          INSERT INTO ErrorLogging VALUES 
            (GETDATE(), @errNumber, @errMessage ) 
    END
    GO

    -- test the code
    USE tempdb
    delete from dbo.TestAT;
    delete from errorLogging;

    BEGIN TRAN 
      INSERT INTO TestAT VALUES (1) 
      EXEC [loopback].[tempdb].dbo.MyLogger @errNumber = 42, @errMessage = N'this will be saved'
      EXEC [tempdb].dbo.MyLogger @errNumber = 66, @errMessage = N'this will NOT be saved'
    ROLLBACK 

    SELECT * FROM TestAT 
    SELECT * FROM ErrorLogging GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how intense your logging is, how about explicit transaction handling with a TRY/CATCH? I'm pseudo coding here, but it gets the point across:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.WhatHaveYou
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @EnoughVariablesToCaptureErrorMessageSeverityEtc.
  BEGIN TRANSACTION Proc
  BEGIN TRY
    <Body of your proc>
    COMMIT TRANSACTION Proc
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @EnoughVariables... = ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), etc.
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION Proc
    INSERT INTO dbo.LoggingTable VALUES (@EnoughVariables....)
  END CATCH
END
```

You could add some more variables and assign them to your logging messages in the CATCH block, too, then re-write them, if you will, after the ROLLBACK.

Comment: Yep - could do that, and in most cases that's an improved solution.  We're handling transactions in the calling code (Java), so in our case we can't

Comment: @JohnLedger, all I know of Java is that I couldn't function without the cup of it that's sitting on my desk. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The key phrase you want to be searching on here is 'Autonomous Transactions' which is a feature built into Oracle, that often wishes to be replicated within a SQL Server scenario. Use that in your searches and you will find a lot of references for how to do it.

It is doable, although a bit more complex - one option is to to create a looped back linked server (link to yourself) and run your log queries against that, setting it to not run in a distributed transaction - that exempts the log query from being within transaction scope.

MSDN Article with the specifics : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: I have to ask though - how come this is such a minor topic?  There aren't a lot of people needing to log messages, whether they be error or debug, or anything in between.  Logging to the database seems like a solid design pattern.

Comment: @JohnLedger, I agree with you.  Coming from C# coding, it seems strange that basic logging like this is not more easy in SQL Server.